# Create a List of Sentences based on Multiple Arrays of Integers and Words

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a list of strings from all possible combinations of multiple arrays.

```
l = ''

zero = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
one = ['boys', 'girls', 'pythons', 'baddies']
three = ['the', 'grandmas', 'bunny's']

# Do something with i, j, k. Iterate...
s = '{0!s} apples brings all the {1} to {2} yard'.format(zero[i], one[j], two[k])
l = l + s + '\n'
```

Expected output, `l`:

```
2 apples brings all the boys to the yard
3 apples brings all the boys to the yard
...
...
5 apples brings all the baddies to bunny's yard
6 apples brings all the baddies to bunny's yard
```

How can I generate a list that exhausts all possible i, j, k, combinations? The above is just an example. In the real world I have seven variables ([i] - [o]).

Answer (score 1):

try itertools for finding combinations,

```
import itertools

l = ''

zero = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
one = ['boys', 'girls', 'pythons', 'baddies']
three = ['the', 'grandmas', 'bunny\'s']
s = '{0!s} apples brings all the {1} to {2} yard'

for combination in itertools.product(zero, one, three):
    l = l + s.format(combination[0], combination[1], combination[2]) + '\n'
print(l)
```

output:

```
2 apples brings all the boys to the yard
2 apples brings all the boys to grandmas yard
2 apples brings all the boys to bunnys yard
2 apples brings all the girls to the yard
2 apples brings all the girls to grandmas yard
2 apples brings all the girls to bunnys yard
2 apples brings all the pythons to the yard
2 apples brings all the pythons to grandmas yard
2 apples brings all the pythons to bunnys yard
2 apples brings all the baddies to the yard
2 apples brings all the baddies to grandmas yard
2 apples brings all the baddies to bunnys yard
3 apples brings all the boys to the yard
3 apples brings all the boys to grandmas yard
3 apples brings all the boys to bunnys yard
3 apples brings all the girls to the yard
3 apples brings all the girls to grandmas yard
3 apples brings all the girls to bunnys yard
3 apples brings all the pythons to the yard
3 apples brings all the pythons to grandmas yard
3 apples brings all the pythons to bunnys yard
3 apples brings all the baddies to the yard
3 apples brings all the baddies to grandmas yard
3 apples brings all the baddies to bunnys yard
4 apples brings all the boys to the yard
4 apples brings all the boys to grandmas yard
4 apples brings all the boys to bunnys yard
4 apples brings all the girls to the yard
4 apples brings all the girls to grandmas yard
4 apples brings all the girls to bunnys yard
4 apples brings all the pythons to the yard
4 apples brings all the pythons to grandmas yard
4 apples brings all the pythons to bunnys yard
4 apples brings all the baddies to the yard
4 apples brings all the baddies to grandmas yard
4 apples brings all the baddies to bunnys yard
5 apples brings all the boys to the yard
5 apples brings all the boys to grandmas yard
5 apples brings all the boys to bunnys yard
5 apples brings all the girls to the yard
5 apples brings all the girls to grandmas yard
5 apples brings all the girls to bunnys yard
5 apples brings all the pythons to the yard
5 apples brings all the pythons to grandmas yard
5 apples brings all the pythons to bunnys yard
5 apples brings all the baddies to the yard
5 apples brings all the baddies to grandmas yard
5 apples brings all the baddies to bunnys yard
6 apples brings all the boys to the yard
6 apples brings all the boys to grandmas yard
6 apples brings all the boys to bunnys yard
6 apples brings all the girls to the yard
6 apples brings all the girls to grandmas yard
6 apples brings all the girls to bunnys yard
6 apples brings all the pythons to the yard
6 apples brings all the pythons to grandmas yard
6 apples brings all the pythons to bunnys yard
6 apples brings all the baddies to the yard
6 apples brings all the baddies to grandmas yard
6 apples brings all the baddies to bunnys yard
```

Comment: The answer loop be simplified a bit: 
`s = '{} apples brings all the {} to {} yard\n'; for combination in itertools.product(zero, one, three): l += s.format(*combination)`